# Nagios check_openmanage

Tags: nagios, dell-openmanage

I've installed openmanage on my dell poweredge 2950 and wanted to integrate check_openmanage through nrpe in my nagios3 monitoring server.

I can execute the check_nrpe!check_openmanage command manually (it returns output from the server I want to monitor when I execute it on my nagios server):

```
./check_nrpe -H example.com -c check_openmanage
Controller 0 [PERC 5/i Integrated]: Firmware '5.2.1-0067' is out of date
```

I've set up the service through:

```
define service{
        use some-service
        hostgroup_name  dell-servers
        service_description dell servers
        check_command            check_nrpe!check_openmanage

}
```

My problem is that on my webinterface I get `status: UNKNOWN` with `status information:     (No output returned from plugin)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the timeout period of the plugin on the remote host. So to increase the timeout I defined a custom command in nagios:

```
  define command{
      command_name timeout_nrpe
      command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -t $ARG2$
 }
```

and custom service:

```
define service{
        use openstack-service
        hostgroup_name  dell-servers
        service_description OMSA checkk
        check_command            timeout_nrpe!check_openmanage!30

}
```

This seemed to fix the issue.